# Вывод текста с ComboBox на TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно реализовать выбор через ComboBox нужной строки и сделать так чтобы он выводился в ReadOnly TextBox.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подписаться на событие `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!